# Import Error on Python 3.4 Exit - Tendo

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, methods, destructor

I've employed the `tendo.singleton.SingleInstance()` class as it provides convenient cross-platform locks on temporary files to inhibit multiple instances.  I'll be using the file lock on a sort-of launcher program called by the cron where I only want 1 instance running.

On both Linux and Windows, it gives errors when Python 3.4 exits (garbage cleanup, I guess).  I'm instantiating `SingleInstance()` as recommended, sleeping, then allowing exit.  I've found that the file lock is removed, but the temp file still remains.

```
import tendo.singleton
import time

me = tendo.singleton.SingleInstance()
print('waiting')
time.sleep(5)
print('done waiting')
```

Error is something like this on Windows 7, similar on Linux.

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method SingleInstance.__del__ of <tendo.singleton.SingleInstance object at 0x000000000251DC50>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\tendo\singleton.py", line 63, in __del__
ImportError: import of 'sys' halted; None in sys.modules
```

This does not occur in Python 2.7.

Taking a close look at the `__del__()` method in `SingleInstace()` class, I've found there are imports:

```
def __del__(self):
    import sys
    import os
    if not self.initialized:
        return
    try:
        if sys.platform == 'win32':
            if hasattr(self, 'fd'):
                os.close(self.fd)
                os.unlink(self.lockfile)
        else:
            import fcntl
            fcntl.lockf(self.fp, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
            # os.close(self.fp)
            if os.path.isfile(self.lockfile):
                os.unlink(self.lockfile)
    except Exception as e:
        if logger:
            logger.warning(e)
        else:
            print("Unloggable error: %s" % e)
        sys.exit(-1)
```

If I comment out these imports (since they are already imported by `singleton.py`) then the `__del__()` destructor works as intended.

So, is this a bug?  Or is the destructor usage just not safe?  Am I just lucky in the test case that Python 3.4 manages to execute the destructor with imports commented out before garage cleanup of `sys`, `os`, and `fnctl`? Or is removal of module import inside the `__del__()` the real fix?

Thanks!

Comment: For me, commenting out the imports just makes it error on 'sys.exit' instead of on 'import sys' :(

Comment: Doubt you're still looking for the answer, but for future viewers, as you guessed, this can happen during object finalization (see [PEP 442](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/)).  The garbage collector has freed the sys module at the time you try to use it.  Fabio (of PyDev) [has suggested an alternative to `__del__` finalizers using `weakref`s' callbacks](http://pydev.blogspot.com/2015/01/creating-safe-cyclic-reference.html) that I believe would also solve this issue.